# Intuition for the formula of Binomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

Let's take an example, let's say that 8% of men have Color Blindness, what is the probability that 2 men in a sample of 10 men have Color Blindness?

My question is:

It makes sense to apply Multiplication Theorem for say the probability of getting 2 Heads if we toss a coin twice. First we toss, 50% of the people get Heads, Then of that new sample space(50% of the original sample space) 50% of the people get Heads, so in total, 50% of 50% of Original Sample Space gets 2 heads, that is, 1/2 of 1/2. But how do we apply it here?

I can't understand, 92% of the given sample doesn't have Color Blindness, 92% of that 92% don't, and so on, until 92% of 92% of 92% of 92% of 92% of 92% of 92% of 92% of 8% of 8% has color Blindness, and why add 10 choose 2 in the front?

It's a bit confusing as to how we start with people who don't have Color Blindness (92% of Sample Space) and end with people with color Blindness by multiplying 92% 8 times then 8% 2 times.

Comment: The problem is ambiguous.  Do you mean *exactly* two men or *at least* two men?  Either way,  the number of ways you can select $k$ people from the total will matter.

Comment: Work a clear example.  Say you toss a fair coin four times.  What is the probability that you get exactly $2$ Heads?  You should see that $\binom 42$, the number of ways to choose two tosses from the four, enters in.

Answer (score 3):

Adam, Bob, Charlie ... Jason are your sample.  Adam and Bob could be the two with colorblindness, or Adam and Charlie, or Charlie and Fred, or etc.

The number of pairs of men you could pick is the binomial coefficient.

Each particular combination of two men having colorblindness has the same probability: $p^2(1-p)^{10-2}$ -- Two with, eight without.

So you have to add together the $\binom{10}{2}$ different ways, each with individual probability $p^2(1-p)^{10-2}$ to get the overall probability $\binom{10}{2} p^2(1-p)^{10-2}$

**In Gory Detail**

First consider $N=1$.  You take a random person off the street, call him Bob, and assess whether he has colorblindness ("cb") or not ("non").  With probability $p$ he is, with probability $1-p$ he is isn't . Note that these probabilities add to $1$.

Later, you do an experiment with $N=2$.  You grab two random people.  There are 4 potential outcomes: non&non, non&cb, cb&non, cb&cb.  These have probabilities $(1-p)^2$, $(1-p)p$, $p(1-p)$, $p^2$.  These sum to 1 (exercise for the reader).  Note that two combinations, cb&non and non&cb, correspond to "1 out the two people sampled are colorblind".

For $N=3$ there are 8 states: non&non&non, non&non&cb, non&cb&non, non&cb&cb, cb&non&non, cb&non&cb, cb&cb&non, cb&cb&cb.  Each has a probability of the form $p^m(1-p)^{N-m}$.  They sum to 1.  Note that there are $3$ states corresponding to the statement $2$ out of the three people sampled are colorblind".

And so on...

Comment: But multiplying the Binomial Coefficient changes the probability of 2 men being colorblind in a sample space of 10 men .How many pairs or how many ways shouldn't change the probability ,why should we consider each and every instance

Comment: Here’s a quick response.  $\sum_{i=0}^{10} p^i (1-p)^{10-i} \neq 1$ so it can’t be the case that “the probability that m men out of N is $p^m (1-p)^{N-m}$.   You need to think about what the complete state space is.

Comment: @user240797 c.f. the update

Comment: @ Dave ,in the case of Coin tossed twice by 100 people  ,after the first toss ,1/2 of the sample space would get Heads ,1/2 as Tails ,let's say that I need to find the probability of getting 2 heads,out of 50% of sample space that got heads (new sample space) 50% will get Heads ,50% will get Tails ,so the probability of getting 2 heads in 50% of 50% of Sample Space,so could you explain the problem that I mentioned (one with color blinded men)in this context as to what percent of sample space is color blind (for the probability of 2 men being colorblind) (ie) what % of % is Color Blind?

Comment: @user240797 For $N=2$ (like in the second to last paragraph).  The probability of getting two colorblind is $p^2$.  The probability of getting two non-colorblind is $(1-p)^2$.  The probability of getting 1 colorblind is $2p(1-p)$; where the factor of $2$ arise because there are two possiblities: the first man is colorblind/the second isn't **or** the second man is colorblind and the first isn't.

Comment: ,we have total outcomes as 4 ,out of that there are 2 possible outcomes where we get a single head ,so the probability of getting a single head is 2/4=1/2,here we are taking the 2 possible outcomes with 1 head into account before calculating the probability right?

Comment: Yes, you need to account for the fact that there are multiple ways to get a given count.

Comment: @ Dave     Pls answer my recent question ,the one with the title about conditional probability ,I tried asking my question in the comment section here,but it's too long.I have tried to provide the link.                                                https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4244767/question-on-usage-of-multiplication-theorm-in-conditional-probability

Answer (score 0):

It's a case of **Bernoulli's trials** , and is very similar to the case of successive throws of coins , say $n$ coins , and we can find the probability of , say $'r'$ heads in $'n'$ successive throws by finding the coefficient of $h^r$ in $(h+t)^n$ , where $h$ and $t$ are probabilty of heads and tails in each throw respectively , and $h+t=1$.

In your example , let's denote $'p'$ as probabilty of having color blindeness , and $'q'$ denoting not having it, and $p+q=1$ . Therefore , $p=\frac{8}{100}$ and $q=\frac{92}{100}$.

We have  to choose from a total of $10$ men , therefore $n=10$.

Therefore , the probability of $2$ men having color blindeness among $10$ men ,is equal to coefficient of $p^2$ in the expansion of $(q+p)^{10}$ , which is given by $${10 \choose 2}{q^{10-2}}{p^2}={10 \choose 2}{q^{8}}{p^2}$$, where $p=0.08$ , and $q=0.92$.