# Question on usage of multiplication Theorm in conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let us take a 100 people who are going to toss a coin randomly twice ,now about 50 people(50% of sample space) get heads on average ,now on second toss 50% of that 50% will get Heads again ,so it makes 50% of 50% of Sample Space the number of people who get heads twice in a row.

Now if I apply the same logic for finding the probability of two men having color Blindness given that there is a probability that a man in random has 8% chance of having Color Blindness,if I take the First person there is 8% chance he is color blind now I multiplying the chances of 2nd man having Color Blindness ,I get the Chance of those two men having Color Blindness ,but  it's not transparent how multiplying them gives me probability of two men having Color Blindness ,I can't understand as clearly as the example with coin flip.

Comment: Draw a square. Color in the left $8\%$ of it. Also color in the top $8\%$ of it. The amount colored in twice is $8\%$ of $8\%$, that is, $.08\times.08$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson ,But I don't get it 8% of the people are colorblind ,what does 8% of 8% mean ,does it mean of the 8% of colorblind population 8% is colorblind ?,I know it sounds stupid ,but this is my understanding of what is happening ,pls explain, btw what do u mean by color top 8% of it ,are you asking me to color inside the initial 8% ?

Comment: The left $8\%$ of the square represents the cases where the first man is color blind. The top $8\%$ represents the cases where the second man is color blind. The common area, that's in both the left $8\%$ and in the top $8\%$, represents the cases where both men are color blind, and its area is $8\%$ of $8\%$. Oh, and "color the top $8\%$ of the square" means exactly what it says; look at the square, don't color the entire top half, don't color the entire top third, don't color the entire top tenth, just color the top $8\%$. Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: @Greg Myerson ,I don't get how you would say that the top 8% represents the case where second man is blind.Pls bear my ignorance

Comment: What is there to stop me from saying that? Imagine every point on the bottom edge of the square represent a man, and we've pushed all the colorblind men all the way over to the left; every point on the left edge of the square represents a man, and we've pushed all the colorblind men to the top. Then every point in the square represents a choice of two men, and the choices where both are colorblind make up a little square in the upper left corner. HAVE YOU TRIED DRAWING A PICTURE?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson ,yes I have drawn  picture of what you're describing  ,I will get a small square to left ,this square is common to the rectangle to the left and rectangle at the top.

Comment: Good. Now, do you see what they represent, and how they answer your question, or is that still unclear?

Comment: Yes ,I think so ,The first 8% (to the left) represents the chances of first person being Colorblind ,The second 8% (at the top) represents the chances of second person being colorblind ,The common area between them represents the chances for both of em being Colorblind,but how does the common area have it's area as 8% of 8%?

Comment: The common area is just a rectangle (indeed, a square) having length $8\%$ and height $8\%$, hence, area $8\%\times8\%$.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I get it now. Would be good to have ur email id ,if I get any math questions in the future

Comment: If you get math questions in the future, post them to this site.

Comment: In the meantime, now that you understand what's happening in this question, let me encourage you to write up an answer, and post it. Nothing like putting together a careful write-up to solidify your knowledge of a topic.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson ,I have tried my best

Comment: @Gerry Myerson pls answer this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246834/question-regarding-the-intuition-behind-greens-theorm

Comment: Sorry, I haven't thought about that kind of question in years. I see another user has posted an answer, I hope you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a square .

1)The square as a whole talks about the likelihood of a person being Colorblind or not .

2)According to the question ,there is a 92% chance that this person is not colorblind ,there is an 8% of him being Colorblind.Sonin order to represent this in terms of area of square ,I consider a strip of rectangle to represent the chances of him being Colorblind.I am planning to position this strip in such a way that it is to the left of the square, meaning that it has the same length as the square ,so in order for the area to be 8% ,the breadth must be 8% of the breadth of the square.So this represents a person's chances of being Colorblind.

3. Now I take another square ,this represents the chances of the other person being Colorblind ,he has the same chances of being Colorblind ,now this time I consider a strip of rectangle at the top ,meaning that it has the same breadth ,so for the area to be 8%,the length must be 8% of original length of the square.
   So now we have two square (two people and their chances of being Colorblind),each having a strip of rectangles ,each representing the chances of a person being Colorblind ,1st rectangle has its breadth the 8% of original breadth,second rectangle has its length the 8% of original breadth .
4. If I place one square over the another the common area has an length that is  8% of original length and a breadth that is 8% of original breadth .
   So the area will be new breadth (8% of original breadth)*new length(8% of original length).Multiplying these values we see that the common area is 6.4% of the original area,this area represents the chances of two person being Colorblind.

[image: Two squares as seen from a bird's eye view]

Comment: I'm glad you did this. Two problems. 1) I'd say the square as a whole talks about the likelihood of *a pair* of people being colorblind. 2) Eight percent times eight percent is not $6.4$ percent, it's only $0.64$ percent. Eight percent is eight out of one hundred, $8/100=.08$, and $.08\times.08=.0064=0.64/100$ which is $0.64$ percent.

Comment: But it isn't wrong to consider two squares overlapping

Comment: ?? I see two *rectangles* overlapping.

Comment: What I'm trying to say that when the squares overlap ,the rectangles overlap,and common area between them indicate the chances of both of them being colorblind

Comment: I still don't see any squares overlapping. I see two rectangles overlapping, and their overlap is a square, and that square represents the times when both are colorblind  (so its area gives the probability that both are colorblind).

Comment: The squares are overlapping from the bird's eye view,bcoz the vertical rectangle belongs to square 1,and horizontal rectangle belongs to square 2 ,you see only one square because it's overlapping and it's hard to distinguish them

Comment: There's just one square, and each rectangle contains it, is the way I see it. But, whatever works for you....

Comment: Yeah ,this seems more convincing to me,thanks for your help. Pls answer this.      https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4248173/question-regarding-finding-a-basis-vector/4248183#4248183

Comment: Looks like it has an answer.

Comment: He didn't provide a convincing answer,he just explained what a unit vector is

Comment: When I looked at the question before, you were asking why it was a unit vector. Now you're asking why it's a basis vector. But if you're not satisfied with the answer that was posted, then let that user know what you still need beyond what he's written.